# MAMP + How to Create a MySQL functions?

Tags: mysql

Someone gave me a mysql function :

```
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` FUNCTION `SQL_DéchiffreDonnée`(Val TEXT) RETURNS text CHARSET utf8
BEGIN
    DECLARE key_str TEXT CHARSET utf8;
    DECLARE init_vector TEXT CHARSET utf8;
    SET block_encryption_mode = 'aes-256-cbc';
    SET init_vector = CAST('---*QZF' AS BINARY); -- RANDOM_BYTES(16);
    SET key_str = SHA2('-----*qfw',512);

RETURN CONVERT(AES_DECRYPT(unhex(Val),key_str,init_vector) USING  utf8);
    END
```

I can't find ***WHERE*** to put it inside mamp / Mysql interface to register it. 
Any hint ?

EDIT

I managed to store the function through the **mysqld** :

```
/Applications/MAMP/Library/bin/mysql --host=localhost -uroot -proot
mysql>use database_name;
mysql>DELIMITER $$
mysql> CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` FUNCTION `SQL_DchiffreDonne`(Val TEXT) RETURNS text CHARSET utf8
    -> BEGIN
    ->     DECLARE key_str TEXT CHARSET utf8;
    ->     DECLARE init_vector TEXT CHARSET utf8;
    ->     SET block_encryption_mode = 'aes-256-cbc';
    ->     SET init_vector = CAST('---*sdf' AS BINARY); -- RANDOM_BYTES(16);
    ->     SET key_str = SHA2('---***',512);
    ->
    ->                RETURN CONVERT(AES_DECRYPT(unhex(Val),key_str,init_vector) USING  utf8);
    -> END
    -> ;
    -> $$
```

But now I can't call the function  :

```
SELECT SQL_DchiffreDonne(NNS) from table_name;
```

gives me an error :

```
SQL query: Documentation
SELECT SQL_DchiffreDonne(NNS) from compte_courant LIMIT 0, 30
MySQL said: Documentation
#1411 - Incorrect string value: 'Val@0' for function unhex
```

Comment: Just run it as SQL?

Comment: how do you know that you have MAMP installed successfully?

Comment: MAMP is successfully installed because I see the server http://localhost:8888/phpMyAdmin/